# Не получается зафетчить запрос от mySQL в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, пишу свой блог, пытаюсь зафетчить запрос к базе данных, пишу prepare->execute, все в порядке, но дописать ->fetchAll не получается, даже сама IDE не подсвечивает, и выдает ошибку.

> connect.php

```
<?php
$driver = 'mysql';
$host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'MyBlog';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '111213Aa';
$charset = 'utf8';
$options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("$driver:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset", "$db_user", "$db_pass", $options);
} catch(PDOException $error) {
    die('Ошибка при подключении к базе данных');
}
```

> queries.php(исполняемый файл)

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

function pre($array) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>';
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";

$data = $pdo->prepare($query)->execute()->fetchAll();
pre($data);
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool in /var/www/PHP/MyBlog(Андрей Андриевский)/app/database/queries.php:13
> Process finished with exit code 255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

execute возвращает true/false в случае успешного/не успешного выполнения

Взяли стейтмент

```
$st = $pdo->prepare($query);
```

Выполняем, в $res попал true/false

```
$res = $st->execute($query);
```

Получаем данные у стейтмента

```
$result = $st->fetchAll();
```

А в вашем варианте вы вызываете метод fetchAll у типа bool

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы пишете свой блог, это очень хорошо!
То, что вы сразу стараетесь с самого начала использовать подготовленные запросы - это просто замечательно.
То, что вы используете подготовленный запрос без входящих переменных - это не очень логично, хотя приемлемо.
То, что вы стараетесь оптимизировать код, избегать ненужных повторений - это хорошо.
То, что вы при этом не читаете документацию - это не очень хорошо.

О том, как выполнить подготовленный запрос в три строчки с помощью прочтения документации вам написали в соседнем ответе.

О том, как можно выполнить в одну строчку запрос без переменных стандартными средствами, можно посмотреть в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

```
$data = $pdo->query($query)->fetchAll();
```

---

Но и подготовленный запрос выполнить в одну строчку конечно тоже можно. Для этого нам понадобится немного такой штуки, как программирование. Напишем простую функцию, которая будет делать за нас prepare и execute (и добавим её в connect.php)

```
function pdo($pdo, $sql, $args = NULL)
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($args);
    return $stmt;
}
```

и теперь, с её помощью, можно написать даже ещё короче

```
$data = pdo($pdo, "SELECT * FROM `users`")->fetchAll();
```

причем, если хотите, эту функцию вполне можно добавить напрямую в PDO, чтобы вызывать вот так

```
$data = $pdo->execute_query("SELECT * FROM `users`")->fetchAll();
```

Это делается с помощью такого механизма, как наследование

Но главное, конечно - не забывать использовать эту функцию, когда в запросе используются переменные, **заменяя их на знаки вопроса и передавая отдельно**

```
$data = pdo("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id=?", [$id])->fetchAll();
```

---

Ну и заодно прочитаем [документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) по установке соединения, и уберем вот это бессмысленное try-catch из connect.php. Плюс уберем бессмысленные же кавычки вокруг переменных. То есть у нас останется просто

```
$pdo = new PDO("$driver:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset", $db_user, $db_pass, $options);
```

charset, кстати, надо поменять на `utf8mb4`.

И я вам **настоятельно не рекомендую** использовать буквы разного регистра в идентификаторах базы данных. Пишите все в нижнем регистре. Если надо разделить слова, то используйте знак подчеркивания. То есть имя базы данных сделайте либо `myblog` либо `my_blog`. И следуйте тому же правилу в именах таблиц и полей. Иначе потом будет очень и очень больно.

Comment: Вы правильно меня поняли, спасибо!!!